# Joomla ImageBrowser Lightbox not working

Tags: joomla, lightbox

I've been using an image browser for Joomla called ImageBrowser. It's great - easy uploads, easy for clients to use, even handles zip file uploads. I have Joomla v. 1.5.15 installed and the newest version of this plugin as well on 3 or 4 of our sites with no fuss or issues.

Recently, the ImageBrowser on one of our sites started acting strangely. It was as if the Lightbox effect that we should have disappeared completely. I compared the settings for the site to another and found they were identical. I couldn't find a solution in the documentation or forums.

Here's the URL to look at: http://neda.us/photos?view=gallery&folder=BSU+12-5-09. You can compare that to another of our sites with the same plugin and settings at South Oak Floors dot COM. You should be able to click on a thumbnail and get a full size view of the image in a Lightbox.

Any help much needed and much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like it's a jQuery plugin, in which case using `$` will conflict with the mootools library which Joomla uses. It's easy to solve, just use this:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
    // put your jQuery code in here
});
```

Whether the library itself avoids jQuery conflicts is another matter, but the above should still work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I just released a new version of the Image Browser component. This new version should address this issue as well as fixing a few other bugs and improving security.

You can download the new version from:
http://imagebrowser.e-noise.com/

Let me know if the new version works as expected.

Best,

Lupo

Comment: I installed the new version but it did not fix the issue. Take a look at the link here:

http://173.192.222.69/~schcc/index.php?option=com_imagebrowser&view=gallery&Itemid=12&lang=en

It is configured to use LightBox mode, but I couldn't get either the LightBox mode or Slider mode to work. It just goes to a new window with the image in it. This is somewhat urgent - any ideas?

Comment: Hi,

I've had a quick look at your site and the problem seems to be another extension clashing with the image browser's Javascript.

When I load the link you posted I get the following Javascript error on line 16:

window.addEvent is not a function

Some other extension is using SqueezeBox and that seems to be the problem. This is likely to be a component called com_k2 that your site is loading.

I hope this helps.

Lupo

Comment: Thanks for the response. We are using the K2 CMS with Joomla on this site and another. Any idea how to fix the problem? Is there a quirks mode or something?

Answer (score 0):

Ur missing your `js`and `css` files for lightbox, embed the code in `index` file and uploaded the files on your server. thanks